# How to parse the data from "rows" object in node.js,express.js,mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I m using the node,express,mysql2 packages .When i m using console.log(rows) ,it is giving me following output:

```
[{"userid": "test","password": "test"}]
```

And here is my Code :

```
var application_root = __dirname,
express = require("express"),
mysql = require('mysql2');
path = require("path");
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host : 'localhost',
user : 'root',
password : '123',
database: "bbsbec"
 });
app.configure(function () {
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public")));
app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

connection.query('SELECT * from pass', function(err, rows) {
     res.json(rows);
     console.log(rows);
   });
```

I just want to know that how can  i parse this "rows" object so that i can retrive both userid and password .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this (this is really basic):

```
   connection.query('SELECT * from pass', function(err, rows) {
     res.json(rows);

     var user = rows[0].userid;
     var password= rows[0].password;

   });
```

Comment: Remember that this only works with one row in the resultset. If there will be more, please use the second answer!

Answer (score 27):

```
[{"userid": "test","password": "test"}]
```

This is an `Array` of `Object`s. So: First loop over the array to get a single object and then extract its properties:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    console.log(row.userid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 connection.query('SELECT * from pass', function(err, rows) {
      data = rows[0];
     let user = data.userid;
     let password= data.password;
     res.json(rows);

   });
```